# how to get the activeElement in puppeteer sharp

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

In order to find the activeElement in javascript puppeteer you use:

`await page.evaluateHandle(() => document.activeElement);`

But i cant find this in Puppeteer Sharp.

is there a way to do this?

I'm trying to find the activeElement, check if it has a certain innerText, and if so, click it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are after a handle, in this case an `IElementHandle` then you use `EvaluateExpressionHandleAsync`

```cs
var activeElement = await (IElementHandle)Page.EvaluateExpressionHandleAsync("document.activeElement");
```

There are more examples on [GitHub](https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp/blob/master/lib/PuppeteerSharp.Tests/JSHandleTests/AsElementTests.cs)